# Can't fully remove margins of elements in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to remove all element margins and padding as I always do, but it doesn't seem to work in Angular 7.

Here you can see that there are still margins: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hG5k.jpg

What I've tried:

Setting margins and padding to 0 in the global Styles.sass file;

```
* 
margin:0
padding:0
```

Comment: Can't say I see the [issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4anekz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css). If you're talking about the space above and below the text it's due to the font. Open devtools and you'll see there's no applied margin/padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has a mechanism to scope styles per component that is on by default.
If you want some style to be injected deeper into one components sub-components you can use the `::ng-deep` pseudo-selector in your component's CSS, or you can define that a component does not follow encapsulation by defining `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component definition.

An example of using `::ng-deep` in your case:

```
::ng-deep * 
margin:0
padding:0
```

More information can be found in the [Components Styles Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Since you did not provide your working example, it might as well just be the height, font-size or line-height of your content. Try checking these properties in the dev-tools.